# Как не округлять данные из файла

Tags: c++

У меня проблема, данные передаются в массив,  но не так как мне бы хотелось .

В общем опишу мой "путь" и то чего я хочу достичь.
В файле P1Am.txt лежат данные

```
 1043.928480752930
 1023.487233880130
 1014.657596748670
 1132.028858770790
 1012.557090294320
 1006.203887562610
 1041.219702992490
 1032.005532206760
 1113.350002788500
 1203.141773433670
 980.619915778275
 1061.732090096410
 1129.337311152790
```

и далее так ровно 128 элементов .
Я вполне нормально раскладываю элементы в переменную obm->stor->AMP[k] , но почему то число 1043.928480752930 превращает в 1043 , именно это округление меня и не устраивает.

```
// test
FILE *fid=fopen("P1Am.txt","rt");
if(fid)
{
    float val=0;
    for(int k=0; k<128; k++)
    {
        fscanf(fid,"%f",&val);
        for(int n=0; n<obm->stor->NT; n++)
        {
            obm->stor->AMP[k*obm->stor->NT+n] = val;
             qDebug() << k+1 << obm->stor->AMP[k];
        }
    }
    fclose(fid);
}
```

Даже когда я менял , на с легка другой вариант результат был тот же , а то и хуже .

```
 // test
FILE *fid=fopen("P1Am.txt","rt");
if(fid)
{
    double val=0;
    for(int k=0; k<128; k++)
    {
        fscanf(fid,"%.12d",&val);
        for(int n=0; n<obm->stor->NT; n++)
        {
            obm->stor->AMP[k*obm->stor->NT+n] = val; // амп я тогда тоже на double менял 
             qDebug() << k+1 << obm->stor->AMP[k];
        }
    }
    fclose(fid);
}
```

Результат был тот же .

Вот попробывал такой вариант , результат очень расстроил ((( печалька (((

```
     //     test
    FILE *fid=fopen("P1Am.txt","rt");
    if(fid)
    {
        double val=0;
        for(int k=0; k<128; k++)
        {
            fscanf(fid,"%d",&val);
            obm->stor->AMP1[k] = val; // создал новую перемен для теста AMP1
            qDebug() << k+1 << obm->stor->AMP1[k];
        }
        fclose(fid);
    }
```

результат :

```
 1 5.1531e-321 
 2 5.1531e-321 
 3 5.1531e-321 
 4 5.1531e-321 
 5 5.1531e-321 
 6 5.1531e-321 
 7 5.1531e-321 
 8 5.1531e-321 
 9 5.1531e-321 
 10 5.1531e-321 
 11 5.1531e-321
```

Что я делаю не так ??

Comment: Возможно, правильно будет работать отделение дробной части запятой, а не точкой?

Comment: Причем тут `qt`? Только из-за `qDebug`? Тогда, можно воспользоваться еще и [QFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/QFile.html) вместо `FILE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз уж вы используете Qt, читайте файл с его помощью:

```
// test
QFile fid("P1Am.txt");
if (fid.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    double val = 0.0;
    while (!fid.atEnd())
    {
        val = fid.readLine().toDouble();
        // дальше ваш код (не проверял):
        for(int n=0; n<obm->stor->NT; n++)
        {
            obm->stor->AMP[k*obm->stor->NT+n] = val;
            qDebug() << k+1 << obm->stor->AMP[k];
        }
    }
}
```

Для максимальной точности используйте тип `double`.

Оставил неизменным ваш код сохранения значений в структуру.

PS: как уже говорили, проверьте тип obm->stor->AMP.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, для такой точности я бы брал тип `double`, а не `float`.

Во-вторых, у меня большие сомнения в том, что тип `obm->stor->AMP[k]` - не целочисленный...

В третьих, вот это - `fscanf(fid,"%.12d",&val);` - просто издевательство какое-то... Трудно даже представить сочетание `.12` и `%d`, да еще при `double`... Что-то мне кажется, что это будет UB...

Или я неверно понял вашу проблему, и вы хотите получить целочисленное значение, просто округление не "математическое"? Тогда обычное округление получается путем, например,

```
int k = std::round(f);
```

Ну, или если С++11 не поддерживается - можно поиграть в

```
int k = floor(f+0.5);
```

раз уж у вас все значения положительные...

Answer (score 0):

По первому коду, добавил вывод в консоль:

```
...
for (int k = 0; k < 14; k++)
{
    fscanf(fid, "%f", &val);
    qDebug() << val;
...
```

Результат:

```
1043.93 
1023.49 
1014.66 
1132.03 
1012.56 
1006.2 
1041.22 
1032.01 
1113.35 
1203.14 
980.62 
1061.73 
1129.34 
1129.34
```

Второй вариант получения значения вообще всегда 0 возвращал.

Почему у вас эти числа без дробного остатка стали можно только догадываться, представляя чем является `obm->stor->AMP`

Comment: 1043.93 а хотелось бы 1043.928480752930. я слегка утрировал . Цель : максимальная точность

Answer (score 0):

Покажите какой у вас тип у `AMP`.

А так же вывод:

```
qDebug() << QLocale::system().name();
```

для разделителей, судя по всему, используется системная локаль, а она (предсказываю), у вас русская, для которой разделителем для дробной связи является `,`.

Если вывод локали русский, а нужна точка в разделителе, используйте `QFile`:

```
QFile file("P1Am.txt");
if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    QTextStream ist(&file);
    ist.setLocale(QLocale::c()); // хотя, судя по документации, используется C локаль по умолчанию.

    while (!ist.atEnd())
    {
        double val;
        ist >> val;
        for (size_t n = 0; n < obm->stor->NT; ++n)
        {
            obm->stor->AMP[k*obm->stor->NT+n] = val; // < непонятен какой тип у AMP, может там int?
            qDebug() << k+1 << obm->stor->AMP[k];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В от еще ответ )) просто "lf" - длинный флоат мне помог ровно 1043.928480752930.

```
  //     test
    FILE *fid=fopen("P1Am.txt","rt");
    if(fid)
    {
        double val=0;
        for(int k=0; k<128; k++)
        {
            fscanf(fid,"%lf",&val);
            obm->stor->AMP1[k] = val;
             qDebug("%.12f",obm->stor->AMP1[k]);
            // qDebug() << k+1 << obm->stor->AMP1[k];

        }
        fclose(fid);
    }
```